# JSF class init-method loads upon page reload

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have a class instantiated like so in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="class1" class="com.action.abc.class1" scope="session" init-method="init1"> </bean>
```

The init1 method is being called along with the constructor for class1 every time the page is reloaded (refresh button in browser).  To my understanding, if the scope is session and not request, the class shouldn't be instantiated again, and instead should reside in the session that's created upon initial page load.  I'm running this on a local weblogic 9.2 instance.  Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I found the issue.  My weblogic server was not setup correctly to keep cookies.  Thanks!

Comment: If you've found a solution, you can always post an answer to your question and then *shudder* accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I found the issue. My weblogic server was not setup correctly to keep cookies. Thanks!